# ¿Cómo compilar en C++11 o superior en DevCPP?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

La versión de **Devcpp** que tengo es la 5.3.3 y el compilador es **TDM-GCC 4.7.1 64-bit Release**.
Estoy usando **Windows 10**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para compilar con `g++` en Dev-C++ (Tengo la version 5.11, pero deben de ser las mismas configuraciones) haces lo siguiente:

1. Vas a Tools o Herramientas:
   [image: Tools o Herramientas]
2. En las opciones te saldra el siguiente dialogo:
   [image: Dialogo de Configuraciones]
3. Haces click en `Settings` y:
   [image: Ajusta la configuracion]

Aqui una prueba de como me funciona, espero que se vea correctamente.
[image: Hola mundo compilando con -std=gnu++11]

Las configuraciones no deben ser tan diferentes en tu version de Dev-C++.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: @NaCI gracias, es justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 3):

ve a Herramientas y en Opciones de compilador añade este comando "-std=c++11" sin las comillas en la parte que dice "Añade los siguientes comandos al llamar al compilador". Le das en aceptar y eso debería compilar tu código con c++11. No te olvides de marcar la casilla de dicha ventana.

Answer (score 2):

Solo para dejar en claro, también puedes compilar con el estándar de C++14, por lo que puedo ver no aparece en las opciones en la cual muestra @NaCl, y creo que esta sería una mejor opción para no tener que estar cambiándolo entre proyecto y proyecto, para eso nos dirigimos a:

*Proyecto->Opciones de proyecto*

y en la pestaña de argumentos para el programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede agregar la linea:

```
-std=c++14
```

El cual sería para c++14, de otra forma:

```
-std=c++11
```

Comment: ¡Muy buena adición! Acabo de mirar en mi Dev-C++ y me di cuenta de que no tengo el estándar C++14, _es una versión vieja_ :P

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo Windows 7 Starter y con Dev 5.11 compilo los códigos de ésta manera:

[image: Dev 5.11]

Comment: Con que estandar de C++ compila su Dev-C++?

Comment: No entiendo a que se refiere con estándar, se refiere a las librerías que utilizo?

Comment: El op pregunta sobre como compilar con el estandar C++11 o superior.

Comment: Hola @GreciaV.P.Valero, creo que tú entendiste cómo le hacía para compilar un código en c++.