# Advertencia en arreglo dentro de estructura

Tags: c++, array, estructuras

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```cpp
struct persona{
    string nombre;
    int montoMes[5]={0};
};
```

Y me aparece las siguientes advertencias:

```
[Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 
[Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

Y marca la linea donde esta 
`int montoMes[5]={0};`
Ya he intentado de todo y no logro resolver nada.

Comment: El warning señala que añadas -std=c++11 o -std=gnu++11 al comando que usas para compilar

Comment: @eyllanesc como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Depende de la herramienta que usas para compilar, ¿Usas alguna IDE o solo la linea de comandos?

Comment: @eyllanesc utilizo Dev++

Comment: Debes hacer lo que señalen en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59754/22539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
int montoMes[5] = { 0 };
```

Eso, en otras circunstancias, sería correcto. Por ejemplo, dentro de una función:

```
int funcion( ) {
  int montoMes[5] = { 0 };
  ...
}
```

Sin embargo, lo estás intentando usar **para inicializar una variable-miembro** de una clase. Y, antes de C++11, para esos menesteres, están **los constructores**:

```
#include <algorithm>

struct persona{
  string nombre;
  int montoMes[5];

  persona( ) {
    std::fill( montoMes, &montoMes[5], 0 );
  }
};
```

Como el propio mensaje te está diciendo, a partir de C++11 se añadió la funcionalidad de inicializar variables-miembro de clase en su propia declaración, haciendo el código mas fácil de mantener: en lugar de colocar todas las inicializaciones en un único punto, se permite colocarlas **en la propia declaración**.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres inicializar la estructura de este modo tal y como estas haciendo, tendras que usar la versión de C++ 11 añadiendo los parametros -std=c++11 o -std=gnu++11 al compilador.
En caso contrario, deja la estructura sin inicializar:

```
struct persona{
    string nombre;
    int montoMes[5];
};
```

E inicializa el valor de montoMes tras la creación de la estructura